# How do I globally add a border to all inline code that uses /lstinline?

Tags: pandoc, rmarkdown

I am using `R Markdown` and `Latex` with `memoir` to compile a book to pdf. I am using `lstset`for the normal code blocks while the inline code is converter and uses `\lstinline`. I would like to globally add a border (like the one in the photo) around all inline code without affecting the normal code examples.

[image: An example of the desired inline code style (this is just HTML no tex)]

EDIT: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\linespread{1}\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  extendedchars=true,
  showspaces=false,
  xleftmargin=5pt,
  framexleftmargin=17pt,
  framexbottommargin=0pt,
  showtabs=false,
}

\surroundwithmdframed[
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  innertopmargin=5pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  linewidth= 0.8pt,
  linecolor= gray,
  roundcorner=0pt
]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

This is an example of some inline code that appears like \lstinline{Env.linen} and another one like \lstinline{Out.ar}.  And this is a normal code block:


\begin{lstlisting}
(
SynthDef(\mySynth4, {
    var signal, env; // declare variables
    env = Env.linen(
        attackTime: 0.05, 
        sustainTime: 0.5, 
        releaseTime: 1);
    signal = 
        LFCub.ar(freq: 220, mul: 0.3) * 
        EnvGen.kr(envelope: env, doneAction: 2);
    Out.ar([0,1], signal);
}).add;
)

g = Synth(\mySynth4);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be related to `memoir` at all so I suggest removing the `memoir` tag. If you want help you need to provide example code that others can test. Given that this is via R markdown (which not many people here know anything about, it is probably best to provide examples of the latex code generated from R Markdown

Comment: @daleif I removed the memoir tag  In terms of the code produced it is simply \lstinline{} tags around the inline code.

Comment: Thanks. You should provide a document that uses `\lstinline` than. People are much more inclined to help if they have code to work with.

Comment: @daleif the problem is that I am compiling from RMarkdown to pdf so any code would be a hello world latex example that uses a \lstinline tag and that is all ‍♂️

Comment: Then provide that. I don't think you are going to get much help else. No-one will know what to do with that image you provided. SO you should help us help you.

Comment: @daleif I've added the MWE 

Comment: I see you're using mdframed, might be an idea to use tcolorbox instead. Might me more powerful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one and the (specific to RMarkdown) solution was to use `tcolorbox` as per @daleif's suggestion in combination with a pandoc lua filter to apply the box globally.

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------
% style all inline code with borders using tcolorbox
% I am using a lua filter to convert \lstinline to \scinline
\usepackage[most, breakable]{tcolorbox}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\scinline}{ s v } {
  verbatim,
  sharp corners,
  colupper=black,
  colback=white,
  arc=0.5mm,
  size=fbox,
  boxsep=1.3pt,
  colframe=code-border} {
    \lstinline[]^#2^
  }
```

the lua filter:

```
if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
  function Code (element)
    local text = element.text
    return {
      pandoc.RawInline(
        'latex', 
        '\\scinline{' .. text .. "}"
      ),
    }
  end
end
```